# Pass currency value to custom field using JavaScript button

Tags: javascript, custom-object, custom-button, opportunity

I need to populate a currency custom field Value_Of_WE_Spend__c on a custom object WE_FEP__c with the value from an opportunity currency custom field Annual_Settlement_Value__c.

I've written the below code, which works without the recToCreate.Value_Of_WE_Spend__c... section but when the button's clicked with this section included, the following error message is displayed:

> {"faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring "GBP 10,000.00' is not valid
>   for the type xsd:double',}

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 

try{ 
    var recToCreate = new sforce.SObject("WE_FEP__c");  
    recToCreate.Account_Name__c = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}';
    recToCreate.Name = '{!Opportunity.Name}';   
    recToCreate.Description__c = '{!Opportunity.Description}';
    recToCreate.Value_Of_WE_Spend__c = '{!Opportunity.Annual_Settlement_Value__c}';

    var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]); 

    if(result[0].success == "true"){
    window.location = "/" + result[0].id + "/e";
    }
    else{
        alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + result[0].errors.message);
    }
}
catch(e){
    alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + e);
}
```

Comment: try setting it as  recToCreate.Value_Of_WE_Spend__c = '{!TEXT(Opportunity.Annual_Settlement_Value__c)}'

Comment: Thanks, that worked, if you'd like to post that answer then I'll select it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the text function to convert the currency field in the actual value. This should fix the issue:

```
recToCreate.Value_Of_WE_Spend__c = '{!TEXT(Opportunity.Annual_Settlement_Value__c)}';
```